# How to calculate "time until date"?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to calculate how many "days, minutes, second" are left until some date. How might one do this using Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the exact environment you're in, but I'll assume you have access to the Foundation framework. I think you want to review [Calculating Temporal Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) from the Date and Time Programming Guide.